# How to do Rounded Corners Image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-layout, rounded-corners

I am using Flutter to make a list of information about movies. Now I want the cover image on the left to be a rounded corners picture. I did the following, but it didn’t work. Thanks!

```
    getItem(var subject) {
    var row = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 150.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
            child: Image.network(
              subject['images']['large'],
              height: 150.0,
              width: 100.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return Card(
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
      child: row,
    );
  }
```

as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1071, accepted):

Use [`ClipRRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) it will work perfectly.

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
    child: Image.network(
        subject['images']['large'],
        height: 150.0,
        width: 100.0,
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did it as you said, and then added `fit: BoxFit.fill`, it looks pretty good.

Comment: Thanks - do you have any idea on how to create a colourful border to the clipRRect'ed image ?

Comment: @iKK - Wrap it in a Container with a BoxDecoration with the appropriate border/borderRadius props as so:

```Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300])),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
          child: Image.network(
            uri,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            width: imageDimension,
            height: imageDimension,
          ),
        ),
      )```

Comment: thanks, a tip : only works with a same width and height

Comment: I am wondering why Image widget has no `borderRadius` parameter.

Comment: Small heads up that ClipRRect can be confused with ClipRect, which doesn't have borderRadius.

Comment: If you use fix hegiht and width like the example, border radius doesn't work!

Answer (score 274):

#### 1. Circular image (without border)

[image]

- ##### Using `CircleAvatar`:

  ```dart
  CircleAvatar(
    radius: 48, // Image radius
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage('imageUrl'),
  )
  ```
- ##### Using `ClipRRect`:

  ```dart
  ClipOval(
    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
      size: Size.fromRadius(48), // Image radius
      child: Image.network('imageUrl', fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
  )
  ```

---

#### 2. Circular image (with border)

[image]

- ##### Using `CircleAvatar`:

  ```dart
  CircleAvatar(
    radius: 56,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8), // Border radius
      child: ClipOval(child: Image.network('imageUrl')),
    ),
  )
  ```
- ##### Using `ClipRRect`:

  ```dart
  Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), // Border width
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, shape: BoxShape.circle),
    child: ClipOval(
      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: Size.fromRadius(48), // Image radius
        child: Image.network('imageUrl', fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```

---

#### 3. Rounded image (without border)

[image]

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
  child: SizedBox.fromSize(
    size: Size.fromRadius(48), // Image radius
    child: Image.network('imageUrl', fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
)
```

---

#### 4. Rounded image (with border)

[image]

```dart
final borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(20); // Image border

Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), // Border width
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, borderRadius: borderRadius),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: borderRadius,
    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
      size: Size.fromRadius(48), // Image radius
      child: Image.network('imageUrl', fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
  ),
)
```

<sub>There are other ways, like using `DecoratedBox` but that would make the answer bit too long.</sub>

Comment: if child image  is not square clipping will be elliptic  in this solution.

Answer (score 116):

You can also use `CircleAvatar`, which comes with flutter

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 20,
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/140x100')
)
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I did extra `backgroundImage: member[index].picture == null
                      ? Image(image: AssetImage('assests/no-image.png'))
                      : NetworkImage(
                          member[index].picture,`

Comment: @saviour123 not every image with rounded corners is a 'avatar'. Accepted one is the generic answer.

Comment: Can't set a height or width with this widget, which is problematic.

Answer (score 76):

Try this instead, worked for me:

```
Container(
  width: 100.0,
  height: 150.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover, image: NetworkImage('Path to your image')),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
    color: Colors.redAccent,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Your aswer is definitely helpful, thanks! But what if content of a container is not just an image but a widget? Any idea?

Comment: Using this is giving me a runtime error. There are two elements in a "Stack". First element need to be an image with round corners for which I am looking for an answer.

Comment: This is the best answer. The border property of `Container` should be used before `ClipRRect` because it is costly on the processor. If you use `Image.asset()` or `Image.network()` , this will not work in the image property of `Container` so you can use `AssetImage()` and `NetworkImage()` instead respectively.

Answer (score 27):

Try this, with CircleAvatar and load image with [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image).
[image]

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 45,
  child: ClipOval(
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl:  "https:// your image url path",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
    ),
  ),
),
```

2. if you want border also, then add

```dart
backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
```

inside this

[image]

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 45,
  backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  child: ClipOval(
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: "https:// your image url path",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 23):

```
   Container(
      width: 48.0,
      height: 48.0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: new DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: NetworkImage("path to your image")
        )
    )),
```

Answer (score 17):

This is the code that I have used.

```
Container(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 200.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage('Network_Image_Link')),
    color: Colors.blue,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
  ),
),
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 14):

For image use this

```
ClipOval(
    child: Image.network(
        'https://url to your image',
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
);
```

While for Asset Image use this

```
ClipOval(
    child: Image.asset(
        'Path to your image',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 13):

We can use following ways to create Rounded Corners Image in Flutter.

[image]

**Container:**

```
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 120,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  decoration:  BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15) // Adjust the radius as needed
  ),
  child: Image.network(
    'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

**Card:**

```
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), // Adjust the radius as needed
  ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  elevation: 5.0,
  child: Image.network(
    'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300',
    width: 150,
    height: 120,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

**ClipRRect**

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), // Adjust the radius as needed
  child: Image.network(
    'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 150,
    height: 120,
  ),
)
```

**Physical Model:**

```
PhysicalModel(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    elevation: 5.0,
    child: Image.network(
      'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300',
      width: 150,
      height: 120,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ))
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use ClipRRect like this :

```
  Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/pic13.jpeg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

you can set your radius, or user for only for topLeft or bottom left like :

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(25)
                ,bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/pic13.jpeg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: This one worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

With new version of flutter and material theme u need to use the "Padding" widgett too in order to have an image that doesn't fill its container.

For example if you want to insert a rounded image in the AppBar u must use padding or your image will always be as high as the AppBar.

Hope this will help someone

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {
            print ('Click Profile Pic');
        },
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ClipOval(
                child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/profile1.jpg',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 6):

Use ClipRRect with set image property of fit: BoxFit.fill

```
ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          child: Image(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: AssetImage('images/image.png'),
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 6):

**Output:**

[image]

Using `BoxDecoration`

```
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              width: 86,
              height: 86,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VpX0.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                ),
              ), 
           ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Use ClipRRect it will resolve your problem.

```
      ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                Constant.SERVER_LINK + model.userProfilePic,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this Way in this circle image is also working + you have preloader also for network image:

```
new ClipRRect(
     borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
     child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder:'asset/loader.gif',
          image: 'Your Image Path',
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This it works well.

```
Container(
  height: 220.0,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
       topRight: Radius.circular(10),
    ),
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: NetworkImage(
        photoUrl,
      ),
     ),
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone struggling to add a rounded corner image as an item of `ListView`:

```dart
FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown, // This helps in shrinking the ClipRRect to the size of the Image
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    child: Image.asset(
      'assets/app-icons/app-icon.png',
      width: 96,
      height: 96,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Image all side rounder corner try this one**

```
Container(
 // height and width depend on your your requirement.
 height: 220.0,
 width: double.infinity,
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   // radius circular depend on your requirement
   borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
    Radius.circular(10),
    ),
    image: DecorationImage(
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
     // image url your network image url       
      image: NetworkImage(
       "dynamic image url",
     ),
    ),
   ),
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Circular Image in Flutter**

```
ClipRRect(
child: Image.asset(
"assets/images/ic_cat.png",
width: 80,
height: 80,
),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
))
```

**If U want only corners of image then simple change the BorderRadius.circular like below**

```
ClipRRect(
child: Image.asset(
"assets/images/ic_cat.png",
width: 80,
height: 80,
),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
))
```

Answer (score 1):

user decoration Image for a container.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final alucard = Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
          )
        )
    );
```

Comment: the BoxFit.fill distortions the image, and if you use contain the border radius is lost.