# Round Corners to images in Image.asset in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three images(images.asset) in a Column wrapped by Row and I want to make the corners of the images to be round. I used shape but it seems like that shape didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              Image.asset(
                'assets/cat.jpg',width: 110.0, height: 110.0,
              ),
              shape:Rec
              Text(
                'Tickets',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',width: 110.0, height: 110.0,),
              Text(
                'Buy Tickets',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',width: 110.0, height: 110.0,),
              Text(
                'Prizes',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

**Expected Result**

1. To have rounded corners to images.
2. To handle a click event.

Comment: wrap your image inside `ClipRRect` Widget

Comment: are you looking forward to show images in circle? Or just images with rounded corners?

Comment: just imags with rounded corners

Comment: Then `ClipRRect` should do the work. Please state your exact requirement. Ellaborate if necessary as there are answers and you have also marked as accepted.

Comment: I am not able to explain actually and I accepted the answer because it actually does something but it is not as I wanted.  You can look at this site "http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/round.html" for refernce that what i wnt

Comment: Can you draw a image of the output you are looking for?

Comment: I don't know how to draw here yeah but it exactly the same as you can see it in here the SO profile picture, it is what I want exactly these rounded corners. Is there any platform where I can upload ss and You will be able to see

Comment: Google drive, then share link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F924NEBFAjGqa0L3U9JcFMPlQGLL0zsR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The images in it having border is what I want and I am getting this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13kWSAUe4h2ipvUgCPK5IslyO2WNWt7pQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am answering your question do let me know if it works, and if it helps do mark it as your desired solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do Rounded Corners Image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513429/how-to-do-rounded-corners-image-in-flutter)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Cover your image widget like this.**

With `ClipRRect` widget and include `fit:BoxFit.fill` so that your image could expand to the height and width you have passed.

It will give you your desired output as you shown in the image.

```
 ClipRRect(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
     child: Image.asset(
       'assets/cat.jpg',
        width: 110.0,
        height: 110.0,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
     ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 12):

There are many ways of doing it.

(i). Use `CircleAvatar` (recommended)

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/cat.jpg'),
  radius: 50,
)
```

(ii). Use `ClipOval`

```
ClipOval(
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/cat.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

(iii) Use `ClipRRect`

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/cat.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

---

Answering your 2nd question, if you need to handle click on any image, you can wrap any of the above in `GestureDetector` and use `onTap` property.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: AnyAboveWidget()
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use ClipRRect

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      child:  Image.asset(
        'assets/cat.jpg',width: 110.0, height: 110.0,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This helped but I want something like what we get when we apply this: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
Still there is sharpness any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

> **you can use ClipRRect**
>   [enter link to more detail](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html)

```
new ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0)),
              child: Image.asset(
                "images/filter_white.png",
                color: AppColor.appColor,
                height: 20.0,
                width: 20.0,
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is dynamic for any image you use. It means no matter which image you use it will not look weird.

```dart
  CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: cWhite,
        radius: 50,
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Image.file(
            image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: 100, // x2 (twice) the radius of CircleAvatar
            height: 100, // x2 (twice) the radius of CircleAvatar
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Round Corners to images:**

[image]

There are several widgets in flutter create round corner image.

**Container:**

```
Container(
  width: 120,
  height: 120,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  decoration:  BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15) // Adjust the radius as needed
  ),
  child: Image.asset(
    ''assets/cat.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

**ClipRRect**

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), // Adjust the radius as needed
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/images/bg_login.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
  ),
)
```

**Card:**

```
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), // Adjust the radius as needed
  ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  elevation: 5.0,
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/images/bg_login.jpg',
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

**Physical Model:**

```
PhysicalModel(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    elevation: 5.0,
    child: Image.asset(
     'assets/images/bg_login.jpg',
      width: 120,
      height: 120,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ))
```