# How to add circular image in flutter PDF

Tags: flutter, image, dart, pdf

How to add a Round shape image in flutter pdf.

my image `Container` code is

```
Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: Image(
                          image,
                          height: 70,
                          width: 70,
                        )),
```

I also used `DecorationImage` but this is not working

```
 Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: image, fit: BoxFit.cover))),
```

These 2 methods are not working

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do Rounded Corners Image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513429/how-to-do-rounded-corners-image-in-flutter)

Comment: No, My Question is rounded image add in Flutter pdf. This question is normal screen design

Comment: can I ask what package you're using  for pdf.

Comment: pdf [link][https://pub.dev/packages/pdf]

Answer (score 1):

Check this link
it could be helpfull https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/master/demo/lib/examples/resume.dart

```
  pw.ClipOval(
                      child: pw.Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        color: lightGreen,
                        child: pw.Image(profileImage),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a flutter package that will let you create flutter UI widgets inside your PDf
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf/example

here is an example:

import package

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
```

```dart
  
Future<void> createMyPDF() async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  final image = pw.MemoryImage(
    File('image.jpg').readAsBytesSync(),
  );

  pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
      // build PDF UI
      build: (pw.Context context) => pw.Center(
            child: pw.Container(
              decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                border: pw.Border.all(color: PdfColors.black),
              ),
              child: pw.Image(image),
            ),
          )));
  // save my pdf as exapmle.pdf
  final file = File('example.pdf');
  //write file in storage
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
}
```

call the function on any event to  save pdf file